# Trying to get acronyms from nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am relatively new and learning python. I am trying to write an app that will take a word provided by the user and  give some alternate suggestions on the word. It seems that nltk has most of what I need. I have been looking at some examples and have been able to get it to work as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
    for lemma in wn.synset('car.n.01').lemmas:
        print lemma, lemma.count()
```

This works fine. The problem I am finding is that if the user misspells or pluralizes the word, then I get a crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-2.0.1rc1-py2.6.egg/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1035, in synset
    raise WordNetError(message % (lemma, pos))
nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetError: no lemma 'cars' with part of speech 'n'
```

Based on this error, it looks like it could not find 'cars' as a noun. Is there a way to do a search to see if the word is found, or a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not calling Wordnet the right way:

```
>>> wn.synsets('cars')
[Synset('car.n.01'), Synset('car.n.02'), Synset('car.n.03'),
Synset('car.n.04'), Synset('cable_car.n.01')]
```

Now:

```
>>> for synset in wn.synsets('cars'):
...    synset.lemmas
[Lemma('car.n.01.car'), Lemma('car.n.01.auto'),
Lemma('car.n.01.automobile'),Lemma('car.n.01.machine'),
Lemma('car.n.01.motorcar')]...
```

For the spelling errors thing, I don't think NLTK has builtin features. You can either:

1. Use a library like `pyenchant`, which provides access to some nice C libraries (Myspell, Hunspell). The main problem, IMO, is that you don't get many different suggestions for the misspelled words.
2. Check yourself the word submitted by the user, and propose alternate spellings. This is not a big deal. You can start out by studying what does [this program](http://pythonhosted.org/ngram/tutorial.html) (or use it directly), which provides a good example of how you can build a gram index on a word list.

To get infos about the lemmas:

```
>>> # get one of the lemmas
>>> lemma = wn.synsets('cars')[0].lemmas[0]
>>> lemma
Lemma('car.n.01.car')
>>> dir(lemma)
[...'antonyms', 'attributes', 'causes', 'count',
'derivationally_related_forms', 'entailments', 'frame_ids'... 'name'...]
>>> lemma.name
'car'
```

Use `dir` on each object to check it's properties, and try things out :)

Comment: @thefourtheye - Thanks you have once again answered my question. Now might I ask if there is a way to easily extract the words from car.n.01.auto, etc?

Comment: Just been looking at this. How does it handle acronyms such as OCP (oral contraceptive pills) or USA, or WHO (World Health Organization)?